# How to count the numer of pdf pages in python that has blank pdf page also

Tags: python-2.7, pypdf

I have tried to print the count of pdf document which includes some blank white pdf page using pypdf module. But it avoids the blanks page and print the count of rest of pages. Below is the code.

```
import sys

import pyPdf

from pyPdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf_document = PdfFileReader(file(normalpdfpath,"r"))

normal = pdf_document.getNumPages()
print normal
```

Answer (score 4):

step 1:-

> pip install pyPDF2

step 2:-

```
import requests, PyPDF2, io
url = 'sample.pdf' 
response = requests.get(url)
with io.BytesIO(response.content) as open_pdf_file:
  read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open_pdf_file)
  num_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
  print(num_pages)
```

Comment: is it also possible to extract page dimensions or orientations (landscape/horizontal)?

Comment: Yes, you can. check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232984/how-to-get-pdf-file-metadata-page-size-using-python

Answer (score 2):

You may try this, which worked for me:

```
import re
import os

rxcountpages = re.compile(r"/Type\s*/Page([^s]|$)", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

def count_pages(filename):
    data = file(filename,"rb").read()
    return len(rxcountpages.findall(data))

if __name__=="__main__":
    parent = "/Users/username/"
    os.chdir(parent)
    filename = 'LaTeX20120726.pdf'
    print count_pages(filename)
```

For **Python 3.6+**

```
import re

rxcountpages = re.compile(rb"/Type\s*/Page([^s]|$)", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

def count_pages(filename: str) -> int:
    with open(filename, "rb") as infile:
        data = infile.read()
    return len(rxcountpages.findall(data))

if __name__=="__main__":
    filename = '/Users/username/LaTeX20120726.pdf'
    print(count_pages(filename))
```

Regards

Comment: It's been a while, but this is still useful.
I had to change `data = file(filename,"rb").read()` to `data = open(filename,"rb").read()` -- i.e., `open` instead of `file` -- and `re.compile(r"/Type...` to `re.compile(rb"/Type...` -- i.e., use a binary regular expression.

Answer (score -1):

Just for all your googlers, here is an updated version of [this answer and comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16649820/5125264) that works using built-in packages:

```py
import re

# compile your regex to make it faster
PAGE_COUNT_REGEX = re.compile(
    rb"/Type\s*/Page([^s]|$)", 
    re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL
)

def get_page_count(floc, regex=PAGE_COUNT_REGEX):
    """Count number of pages in a pdf"""
    with open(floc, "rb") as f:
        return len(regex.findall(f.read()))

get_page_count("path/to/your/file.pdf")
```